# Check if there is something in string

Tags: xcode

I want to check if there is something in string.
Its like that:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"h" withString:@"a"
```

But I want to check if there is "h" in the string.

Comment: Try `BOOL hExists = ([myString indexOfSubstring:@"h"] != NSNotFound);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`[NSString rangeOfString: @"h"]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a), where if a "h" character exists in the string, the NSRange returned by that method will be valid.

I.E.

```
NSRange rangeOfTheCharacterIWant = [myString rangeOfString: @"h"];
if(rangeOfTheCharacterIWant.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog( @"h exists!");
} else {
    NSLog( @"h does not exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
NSString *theString = @"just any string that you want";
NSRange match;
match = [theString rangeOfString: @"you"];
if (match.location == NSNotFound)
          NSLog (@"Sorry, not found.");
else
          NSLog (@"Match found at index %i", match.location);
```

enjoy.